# How password change of mysql for MAMP and XAMPP works?

Tags: mysql, security, xampp, mamp

Till now I was using MAMP(for drupal web development) on the my macbook and was not aware that there is something called mysql password. recently when I was installing XAMPP on windows, while searching I came to know mysql password needs to be setup for the security, hence I thought I apply to MAMP also.

So, when I am watching videos on [youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X4FvTPkRUoI), mostly everybody changing default `'root'` password by going to `/phpmyadmin/priviledge/change password`. And apply to new password. now if we start the server it is showing the Access denied, which is obvious as we changed password. Hence these all people suggesting to go to bin(or library)/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php and apply the new password there, and same way other two files where password needed to change from 'root'. All same for XAMPP.

Now, what we are doing different here, instead of 'root' we are changing it to 'newpassword'. and applying this all change to all internal files. If there was something login box, like gmail, which ask for password before login, I can understand there is a security check step. But in above set up, we are providing password to all that internal files, so it can go through. So where does security applies by changing password of mysql and simultaneously providing it to all that files.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: What is the need of changing the mysql default 'root' password?

Answer (score 0):

The question here is:

**Why should I change standard passwords** (not just once but periodically)

Im not sure if this is the right platform to discuss this. You probably want to ask this question on https://security.stackexchange.com/ or maybe will find answers there.

One of the main reasons is of course, that **everyone knows the standard password.**

Imagine, your server is accessible in the whole network or worse: from internet (depends on your settings).

Comment: I was not aware of that site. If I was, I would have asked there. Thanks for providing that, Appreciated. But as you have took interest, let me explain something what I want to say. Now, we changed the password, and that password we are providing to config files in php, so it does not let us stop by automatic login. Now, we have created system of automatic login. So, same way will not anybody come to mysql-database without password as we did? Or will that auto-login be limited to our computer/server only, and will it ask password when other visitor will come to our IP address?